# I don't want to show popup model on past date slot using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using tui calender https://ui.toast.com/tui-calendar and I want to hide popup model on past dates slots but unfortunatly popup is showing when i click to past date slot please help me how can i hide on past date ? thanks.

[image]

**Jquery**

```
 $(".tui-full-calendar-time-date").on('dblclick', function(){
    $('#addItem').modal('show');

    setTimeout(() => {
    var date = $(".date").val();
    var CurrentDate = new Date();

    var current =  moment(CurrentDate).format('DD');
    console.log("Current date",current);

    var selectedDate =  moment(date).format('DD');
    console.log("selected date",selectedDate);

    if(current > selectedDate ){
        $('#addItem').modal('hide');
    }else{
        $('#addItem').modal('show');
    }
    }, 5);
    // });
});
```

Comment: Maybe this [reference](https://github.com/nhn/tui.calendar/issues/520#issuecomment-850497095) can help you

Comment: please help me a/c to my code

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: I can surely tell you that this plugin itself has some option to disable past date events like other jQuery date time pickers have.

Comment: please can you share with me some code for this?